# WebDataRocks Pivot - Excel export not displaying time part when data type is set as datetime?

Tags: webdatarocks

Excel export - The example(for datetime datatype) provided on the website documentation exports just the date part. https://www.webdatarocks.com/doc/data-types-in-json/

PDF exports date and time fine. The issue is only with excel. How can I export date and time in excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebDataRocks seems to export date along with time. However, Excel applies default date formatting and does not display the time part. Try changing the date formatting of the exported file (right-click on the corresponding cell --> choose "Format cells..." option --> choose appropriate formatting).